# Identical Makefile nomenclature for using variable on different build commands with different results

Tags: makefile, compiler-flags, cflags

There are three programs build by this Makefile. They follow the same pattern, but produce different build commands when run. Specifically, I require compilation with `c++11` but can only achieve this on one of the build commands. Why is this?

Makefile:

```
CXX=g++
RM=rm -f
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -g -Wall $(shell root-config --cflags)
LDFLAGS=-g $(shell root-config --ldflags)
LDLIBS=$(shell root-config --libs)
SOURCES=generic_queue.cpp map_compare.cpp vector_search.cpp
OBJS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(SOURCES) generic_queue_test list_of_lists map_compare_test vector_search_test

# Note that $(CFLAGS) is used in the $(CXX) ... command
# each time that a .o file is built.

vector_search_test: $(OBJS) vector_search_test.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o vector_search_test vector_search_test.o $(LDLIBS)

vector_search_test.o: vector_search.cpp vector_search.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c vector_search.cpp -o vector_search_test.o

generic_queue_test: $(OBJS) generic_queue_test.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o generic_queue_test generic_queue_test.o $(LDLIBS)

generic_queue_test.o: generic_queue.cpp generic_queue.h fixed_priority_queue.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c generic_queue.cpp -o generic_queue_test.o

list_of_lists: $(OBJS) list_of_lists.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o list_of_lists list_of_lists.o $(LDLIBS)

list_of_lists.o: list_of_lists.cpp list_of_lists.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c list_of_lists.cpp -o list_of_lists.o

map_compare_test: $(OBJS) map_compare.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o map_compare map_compare.o $(LDLIBS)

map_compare.o: map_compare.cpp map_compare.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c map_compare.cpp -o map_compare.o


clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) generic_queue_test.o list_of_lists.o map_compare.o

dist-clean: clean
    $(RM) generic_queue_test list_of_lists map_compare
```

Output:

```
g++    -c -o generic_queue.o generic_queue.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -pthread -m64 -I/usr/include/root -c map_compare.cpp -o map_compare.o
g++    -c -o vector_search.o vector_search.cpp
```

We see that only the second `g++` command fully utilizes `CFLAGS` variable. Why? Does it have to do with the `$(shell ...)` portion of the `CFLAGS` variable?

Edit:
Was able to solve my problem by changing the name of the object file `vector_search_test.o` to `vector_search.o` Why did that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of bugs in your makefile, adding up to this behavior.

First consider `OBJS`, which contains

```
generic_queue.o map_compare.o vector_search.o
```

These files are prerequisites of other targets, but you never actually use `generic_queue.o` or `vector_search.o`. **Bug #1: you have extra prerequisites by mistake.**

These files are prerequisites of other targets, so Make must build them. But how? You have provided rules for three object files:

```
vector_search_test.o: vector_search.cpp vector_search.h
    ...

generic_queue_test.o: generic_queue.cpp generic_queue.h fixed_priority_queue.h
    ...

list_of_lists.o: list_of_lists.cpp list_of_lists.h
    ...

map_compare.o: map_compare.cpp map_compare.h
    ...
```

That last one will do for `map_compare.o`, but **you have given no rules for `generic_queue.o` or `vector_search.o`** (and there's really no reason you should, since you never use them). But Make knows how to perform certain standard builds, such as `foo.cpp => foo.o`. If you don't provide a rule, Make will use its implicit rule, which works out to something like this:

```
generic_queue.o: generic_queue.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c generic_queue.cpp -o generic_queue.o
```

This is very similar to the rules you wrote. In fact, you probably wouldn't have noticed the difference -- and you could have omitted your rules and let Make rely on this one, but **Bug #2, you added your flags `-std=c++11 -g -Wall whatever` to the wrong variable.** Make uses `CXXFLAGS` to hold flags for the C++ compiler; you added yours to `CFLAGS`, which is for the C compiler.

(I've left out [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) and [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) since you don't seem to know about them-- I urge you to learn them, they're very useful, but that's for another day.)

Comment: simple to understand, thanks. this is an old makefile for a series of test programs, but i don't tend to write makefiles much anyways. If u have time, how would u edit this to use `pattern rules` and `automatic variables`?

Comment: @errolflynn: Look at the manual section I cited, and play around with the tools. And decide where and why to insert "_test" in file names; it's not clear to me. If you need more help, my freelance rates are quite reasonable, all things considered.